# Leer USBs con Python3 (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, usb

Estoy intentado traducir de MBus (viene por USB) a ModBus (Se va por IP), pero estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de leer los datos desde USB.

He mirado por internet y he encontrado una herramienta con la que leer USBs, PyUSB, pero no entiendo cómo funciona, de hecho no consigo que funcione, me da error del bakcnend. He buscado sobre el error y algunas páginas dicen que hay que tener el libusb o libopenusb corriendo en el sistema, me he descargado los dos pero no se cómo hacer que funcionen .

OpenUSB:

[image: openysusb]

LibUSB:

[image: libusb]

El código py que estoy usando(copiapega de github):

[image: code]

y el error que me da:

[image: error]

Gracias y un Saludo

Comment: Sube el código directamente, mejor que una imagen. Así la ayuda puede ser mejor y mas rápida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyUsb usa `ctypes.find_library` para intentar encontrar las librerías dinámicas del backend, en Windows esto es simplemente buscar en el PATH.

Lo más simple en mi opinión (para `libusb 1.x`) es:

- Ve a la página oficial de libusb, https://libusb.info/, luego al menú <kbd>Downloads</kbd> y por último a <kbd>Latest Windows Binaries</kbd>
- Una vez descargado el .zip, descomprimelo. Te encontrarás varias carpetas, lo que te interesa es `MS32` y `MS64`. Si usas Python 32 bits usa `MS32` si usas Python 64 bits usa `MS64`. Elegida la carpeta correcta, dentro de ella encuentras otra carpeta llamada `dll`. Copia y pega su contenido donde lo desees, en el mismo sitio que tienes tu script si quieres.
- Ahora solo queda cargar el backend de forma explícita:

  ```
  import usb
  import usb.backend.libusb1 as libusb1

  backend = libusb1.get_backend(find_library=lambda _: "/backends/libusb-1.0.dll")
  dev = usb.core.find(backend=backend)

  print(dev)
  ```

Cambia odviamente `"/backends/libusb-1.0.dll"` por la ruta donde has copiado el archivo, si es la misma que la de tu script basta con `"libusb-1.0.dll"`